# How to solve the N-Queens problem using stack?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, stack, n-queens

I have to solve the N Queen problem using stack in c language. In the N Queen problem we have to place N chess Queens in an N x N matrix such that no queen can attack the other. Here's what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    int maxsize;    
    int top;
    int *items;
};

struct stack* newStack(int capacity)
{
    struct stack *pt = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
 
    pt->maxsize = capacity;
    pt->top = -1;
    pt->items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity);
 
    return pt;
}

int size(struct stack *pt) {
    return pt->top + 1;
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *pt) {
    return pt->top == -1;                   
}

int isFull(struct stack *pt) {
    return pt->top == pt->maxsize - 1;      
}

void push(struct stack *pt, int x)
{
    if (isFull(pt))
    {
        printf("\nOverflow");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pt->items[++pt->top] = x;
}
int peek(struct stack *pt)
{
    if (!isEmpty(pt)) {
        return pt->items[pt->top];
    }
    else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *pt)
{
    if (isEmpty(pt))
    {
        printf("\nUnderflow");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return pt->items[pt->top--];
}

void print(struct stack *s,int n) {
  int Size = size(s);
  struct stack *temp = newStruct(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    int col;
    col = pop(s);
    push(temp,col);
    for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
      if (j == col){
        printf("Q ");
      }
      else{
        printf("* ");
      }
    }
             
    printf("\n");
  }
  while (isEmpty(temp) == false) {
    push(s,pop(temp));
  }
  printf("\n");
}
     

bool isValid(struct stack *ptt, int currentPosition, int n) {
  currentPosition=0;
  if (isEmpty(ptt)) {
    return true;
  }
  int Size = size(ptt);
  int arr[n][n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      arr[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  int colStore[size(ptt)];
  for(int i = 0;i<Size;i++){
    colStore[i]=0;
  }
  int positionRow = n-Size-1;
  int positionCol = currentPosition;
  bool isvalid =  true;
  for (int i = 1; i <= Size; i++) {
    int col = pop(ptt);
    colStore[i-1] = col;
    if (col == positionCol) {
      isvalid = false;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0, row = n-Size; i < Size; i++, row++) {
    arr[row][colStore[i]] =1;
  }
  for (int i = sizeof(colStore)-1; i>=0; i--) {
    push(ptt,colStore[i]);
  }
  if (!isvalid) {
    return false;
  } 
  for (int i = positionCol-1, j = positionRow+1; i >= 0 && j < n; i--, j++) {           
    if (arr[j][i] == 1)
      return false;
  }
  for (int i = positionCol+1, j = positionRow+1; i<n && j<n; i++,j++) {
    if (arr[j][i] == 1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int solve(struct stack *p,int n){
  
  int currentPosition = 0;
  int counter = 0;        
  while (true) {
    bool isvalid = false;
    while (currentPosition < n) {
      if (isValid(p, currentPosition, n)) {
        push(p,currentPosition);
        currentPosition = 0;
        isvalid = true;
      } else {
        currentPosition++;
      }
    }
    if (!isvalid) {
      if (isEmpty(p)) {
        printf("\nEnd");
        break;
      } else {
        currentPosition = pop(p);
        currentPosition++;
      }
    }

    if (size(p) == n) {
      print(p,n);
      currentPosition = pop(p);
      currentPosition++;
      counter++;
    }
  }

  if (counter>0) {
    printf("\nNumber of solutions found: %d",counter);
  } else {
    printf("\nNo solution found");
  }
         
}

int main() {
  
  int n;
  printf("\nEnter n: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  struct stack *pt = newStack(n);
  solve(pt,n);
}
```

But it is showing the error: `signal: segmentation fault (core dumped).`
I've used a debugger and found out that the problem occurs at line 116 :

```
arr[row][colStore[i]] =1;
```

Comment: Ok, so the next step is to look at what you have at that point:  What is `row`?  What is `i`?  And what is `colStore[i]`?  All of those values are being used as indices, and one of them must be out of range.  Which one is it?  And why is it out of range?

Comment: In `print()` you're using uninitialized `temp`.

Comment: @TomKarzes according to the debugger colStore[i] is out of range but I don't understand why

Comment: @pmg i initialized temp and it's still showing the same error

Comment: @user16959642 Ok, so what you want to do is find out where `colStore[i]` is being set to the bad value.  Keep working back until you find your mistake.

Comment: Unrelated (?): `free()` the memory you no longer need.